# Basic Topology: Countable Complement Topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $B$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$.  In the topological space $(\Bbb R,\mathscr{T})$, if $B$ is not closed, then $B$ is dense.

$\mathscr{T}$ is defined as the countable complement topology, which is defined as the collection of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that either $U = X$, $U=\varnothing$, or $X - U$ is countable.

I've tried to develop multiple counterexamples and I always find that $B$ is dense.  How would you start a proof like this?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $B$ is not closed, then $\Bbb R\setminus B$ is not open, so $B$ is uncountable. Now show that every non-empty open set must have non-empty interesection with $B$; this is pretty nearly immediate from the definition of the co-countable topology.

Comment: By the definition of co-countable topology and closure, if B is not countable and not closed, then Cl(B), which is the intersection of closed sets and the smallest closed set containing B, is going to be R.  Is that correct?

Comment: @NUG: Yes, that’s correct, if you show that $\Bbb R$ is the only uncountable closed set. If your definition of *dense set* is that its closure is the whole space, then that’s a reasonable way to go. I was thinking in terms of the (equivalent) definition that a dense set is one that intersects every non-empty open set.